# Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UIApplicationRotationFollowingController: 0x100c75280>

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm working through some crash logs for an enterprise iOS application.  My users get the following crash frequently.

> main
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a
>   nil modal view controller on target
>   UIApplicationRotationFollowingController: 0x100c75280.'
>   AppDelegate.swift, line 13

There are a lot of reports of this occurring when presenting this MFMailComposeViewController without first checking if the device is configured for email.  This is *not* the case in my application though.

Does anyone know in what cases this might occur?

Comment: We get `Application tried to present modally an active controller <UIApplicationRotationFollowingController: 0x101621120>.
-[EventsViewController pushDetailViewController]` in our CrashAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to debug without seeing your code... Can you recreate the crash in Xcode with an Exception breakpoint to see whats going on?

Otherwise all I could suggest would be to look at line 13 of your AppDelegate and try to work out why whatever ViewController your trying to present has not been initialised for some reason?

Comment: The only time we see this crash is when it's reported by our crash analytics.  We are unable to reproduce in Xcode. This application has tens of thousands of lines of code and because the crash analytics reports it happening in main, it could originate anywhere including the many frameworks that are part of our app.  Line 13 of AppDelegate is the AppDelegate class header so this is also of limited use.

Comment: Hm that is tricky then. If you're not displaying too many modals in the app you could try taking a look at what modals your presenting (including UIAlertControllers) to see if you think there are cases they could be nil. Otherwise, if you're using any advertising libraries I find they're often to blame (trying to display fullscreen interstitials for example)?